# Warmup Script for SharePoint 2010 in two server Web farm

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, warm-up

Can anybody provide a copy of, or a link to, a reliable powershell warm-up Script for SharePoint 2010.

Ideally I want this to run shortly after the app pool has recycled overnight.

Our configuration is two front end Web servers in a load balancer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script from MSFT employee which will handle the load balanced environment. 
[Warm-up Script for Web Front End Servers (WFE) in Load Balanced SharePoint Farms](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scottstewart/2014/09/29/warm-up-script-for-web-front-end-servers-wfe-in-load-balanced-sharepoint-farms/)

These are the steps:

1. OPEN POWERSHELL ISE OR POWERSHELL AS A FARM ADMIN
2. COPY AND PASTE THE POWERSHELL BELOW (Between the "#--------------------------")
3. TEST THE SCRIPT TO ENSURE NO ERRORS OCCUR
   SAVE THE FILE AS A .PS1 TYPE IN A DESIGNATED LOCATION e.g. c:\powershell\warmupscript.ps1
4. SCHEDULE A WINDOWS TASK TO RUN AFTER THE LAST APPLICATION POOL IS RECYCLED (4am should be safe)

   ### PowerShell Starts here

   ## --------------------------------------------------

   Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction silentlycontinue

   ```
   function get-webpage([string]$url,[System.Net.NetworkCredential]$cred=$null)
    {

      $bypassonlocal = $false
      $proxyuri = "http://" + $env:COMPUTERNAME
      $proxy = New-Object system.Net.WebProxy($proxyuri, $bypassonlocal)
      $wc = new-object net.webclient
      $wc.Proxy = $proxy
      if($cred -eq $null)
      {

        $cred = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials;

      }

      $wc.credentials = $cred;
      return $wc.DownloadString($url);
    }

    $cred = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials;
   ```

   ### This can be used if required to force using certain credentials

   ```
    #$cred = new-object    System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password","machinename")
   ```

   ## Get the Web Apps

   $apps = get-spwebapplication # -includecentraladministration (Central admin is not included as it is not running on my WFE Server)

   foreach ($app in $apps) {
      #Get the Site Collections
      $sites = get-spsite -webapplication $app.url -Limit All

   ### UNCOMMENT THE 2 LINES BELOW IF YOU ONLY WANT TO USE THIS AT SITE COLLECTION LEVEL - Not required if Sites are warmed up.

   #write-host $app.Url;
      #$html=get-webpage -url $app.Url -cred $cred;

   ###COMMENT OUT BETWEEN THE "=======" IF THERE ARE TOO MANY WEBs i.e. Sites and you don't want to warm them up.

   #==================

   ```
   foreach ($site in $sites) {
     foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
     #get the webs i.e. Sites
         write-host $web.Url;
         $html=get-webpage -url $web.Url -cred $cred;
    }
   }
   #=================
   ```

   }

   ## --------------------------

Comment: Thanks - this looks good. Does this have to be run on each server with IIS, or just one of the Web Front End Servers?